# Move existing div to the body of HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to move an existing div which is inside another one to the body of HTML.
For example i have:

```
<body><div1><div2>blah</div2></div1></body>
```

I would like it to make:

```
<body><div1></div1><div2>blah</div2></body>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Suggestion 1 – read the following docs: http://api.jquery.com/prepend/ ("If a single element selected this way is inserted elsewhere, it will be moved into the target (not cloned)")

Comment: Yes i did tried, i was missing '#' i think, got it corrected using @akluth solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your divs some IDs:

```
<body>
    <div id="one">
        <div id="two">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Then use appendTo

```
$('#two').appendTo('body');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div2').appendTo('body');
```

(you'll have to change div2 to a proper selector of course)

Answer (score 0):

use some combination of remove and append to achieve ur out put.

[jQuery Remove Method](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

[jQuery Append Method](http://api.jquery.com/append/)